# Melon.js Space Invaders Project - Grunt config is clearing resource file

Tags: gruntjs, melonjs

I was trying to replicate the Space Invaders Project of Melon.js. It uses Grunt and the initial configuration is clearing the file that contains the player images.

```
resources: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      dest: 'build/js/resources.js',
      varname: 'game.resources',
    },
    files: [{
      src: ['data/bgm/**/*', 'data/sfx/**/*'],
      type: 'audio'
    },{
      src: ['data/img/**/*.png'],
      type: 'image'
    },{
      src: ['data/img/**/*.json'],
      type: 'json'
    },{
      src: ['data/map/**/*.tmx', 'data/map/**/*.json'],
      type: 'tmx'
    },{
      src: ['data/map/**/*.tsx'],
      type: 'tsx'
    }]
  }
},
```

How can I update the config so it doesn't clear the file /build/js/resources.js?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use the gruntfile as-is, you should let it construct the resources file based on resources in the source directory. In other words, do not hand-edit the files in the `build/` directory.

As an example, if you want to add a new `png` image to the `resources.js` file, just put the image file into the `data/img/` subdirectory and the build process will correctly add it to `resources.js` for you.